# Can you 'force' a CSS keyframe animation to it's final state using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, keyframe

I have CSS keyframe animations that are triggered by scroll behavior. If the user is scrolling too fast, I'd like to be able to send some of the animations to their 'finished/final' state using JavaScript given that the animations build off of each other.

Say I have a 3000ms animation that I decide I want to finish after 1500ms has passed -- Is it possible to force this CSS keyframe animation to finish early using JS?

** PS -- I'm **not** talking about persisting the final frame's properties using the forwards fill-mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using class to control status like this:

```
.play{
  animation: animationFrames ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease 5s;
  -moz-animation: animationFrames ease 5s;
  -o-animation: animationFrames ease 5s;
  -ms-animation: animationFrames ease 5s;
}

.end{
    transform:  translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform:  translateX(100px);
    -webkit-transform:  translateX(100px);
    -o-transform:  translateX(100px);
    -ms-transform:  translateX(100px);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#end').click(function(){
    $('#box').removeClass('play').addClass('end');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2Gsh/

Comment: Having a bit more luck with this approach. I need to smooth it out a bit, but it is working so far. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleSuss and emn178, the fall back for this method is that you need to hardcode the ending styles for all animation instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply change the animation duration to conclude the animation faster,

```
elementWithAnimation.style.animationDuration="1500ms";
```

You will need browser prefixes, for example for webkit:

```
elementWithAnimation.style.webkitAnimationDuration="1500ms";
```

Comment: Hm. Tried this but doesn't seem to work. Even added an '!important' just to see if it was being overridden by another rule.

Comment: @KyleSuss This is the bare-bone line. You will need to add the browser prefixes. Updated the answer with an example for webkit.